# Correctly display a graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, miniconda

I need a little help with a jupyter notebook that I am working. I am using miniconda for windows 64.

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Función original
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
x = x[:, np.newaxis]

# Datos de la función
np.random.seed(2)  # Semilla para replicar los resultados
x_train = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
y_train = np.sin(x_train) + np.random.randint(-1, 2, 50) * 0.3
X_train = x_train[:, np.newaxis]

print("x_train shape", x_train.shape)
print("X_train shape", X_train.shape)

def polinom_n(grado, X_tr, y_tr, x_vals):
    pol_reg = LinearRegression()
    features = PolynomialFeatures(grado)
    X_feat = features.fit_transform(X_tr)
    print(X_feat.shape)
    pol_reg.fit(X_feat, y_tr)
    y_pol = pol_reg.predict(features.fit_transform(x_vals))
    return y_pol

lin_r = LinearRegression()
lin_r.fit(X_train, y_train)  # aprende de las muestras
y_lin = lin_r.predict(x)  # ajusta a todos los valores de x

# Modelo polinomial
y_pol3 = polinom_n(3,X_train,y_train, x)
# Probar valores de 2 a 50
n = 20
y_poln = polinom_n(n, X_train, y_train, x)

# Plot de la figura
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(x, y, "r", label="f(x)")  # Grafica la función original
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color='black')  # Grafica las muestras
plt.plot(x, y_lin, label="reg lineal")  # Grafica la regresión lineal
plt.plot(x, y_pol3, label="poli reg 3")  # Grafica la regresión polinomial
plt.plot(x, y_poln, label="poli reg %d"%(n))
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.ylim(-2.5, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that if I run that code in Google Colab or in another computer with exactly the same conda env, I receive the

[image: Output A]

but on my own computer with Windows 10 I receive

[image: Output B].

I erased my conda env and I created it again; I updated all the packages in my conda env but is not working.

This was the process that I followed to create my virtual env:

1. `conda create -n actumlogos-cpu python=3.6 pip tensorflow keras`
2. `conda activate actumlogos-cpu`
3. `conda install scipy jupyter matplotlib flask-socketio imageio pandas requests scikit-image scikit-learn`
4. `pip install opencv-python moviepy`

The output again: [Output A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kHM7.png)  [Output B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZLUI.png)

Comment: My windows 10 with python 3.7, matplotlib 3.0.3 gives the same output as the first one.

Comment: I recommend not comparing the graphs, but the actual data. are you sure the objects are equivalent?

Comment: Its the same data because i used the same seed